How I can install Posthog-js in apache superset?
Postghog-Js is an analytics tool and I wanted to install this in an Apache superset.
I have explored the superset project structure and found one of the HTML files i.e. tail_js_custom_extra.html where they have mentioned that you can add custom frontend code like Google Analytics etc...
Posthog js also does the interface recording that's why I wanted to use this.
Right now, I have a website let's say vikash.google.com in which I have loaded the superset dashboard via Iframe (Embedded SDK) and I wanted to configure Posthog so that I can track the user activity in the recording.
I tried to install the same and build the project but didn't get any kind of error or console message.
That would be great if you guys could help me here to get a solution for this.
PS: I have already installed Posthog in vikash.google.com and working fine as expected but not able to see the dashboard that are loaded in Iframe.
I have included this code in shared .html file
function posthogInit() {
    if (window.posthog && typeof window.posthog.init === 'function') {
      window.posthog.init('phc_JWxHyM9Pjm7j73pz9N5JQ7KW6WA0AoC2hbwbDmk1AgT', { 
        api_host: 'https://app.posthog.com',
        enable_recording_console_log: true, 
        session_recording: {
          maskAllInputs: false,
          recordCrossOriginIframes: true,
        }
      });
    } else {
      setTimeout(posthogInit, 1000); // Try again after 100ms if PostHog is not loaded
    }
  }
  posthogInit();

And then
cd superset-frontend
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npm run build
Docker down and up but didn't see any logs in network related to posthog.
I have also tried with this code in same .html file
<script>

    console.log('tail_js_custom_extra.html is included'); // Add this line
    !function(t,e){var o,n,p,r;e.__SV||(window.posthog=e,e._i=[],e.init=function(i,s,a){function g(t,e){var o=e.split(".");2==o.length&&(t=t[o[0]],e=o[1]),t[e]=function(){t.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}(p=t.createElement("script")).type="text/javascript",p.async=!0,p.src=s.api_host+"/static/array.js",(r=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]).parentNode.insertBefore(p,r);var u=e;for(void 0!==a?u=e[a]=[]:a="posthog",u.people=u.people||[],u.toString=function(t){var e="posthog";return"posthog"!==a&&(e+="."+a),t||(e+=" (stub)"),e},u.people.toString=function(){return u.toString(1)+".people (stub)"},o="capture identify alias people.set people.set_once set_config register register_once unregister opt_out_capturing has_opted_out_capturing opt_in_capturing reset isFeatureEnabled onFeatureFlags getFeatureFlag getFeatureFlagPayload reloadFeatureFlags group updateEarlyAccessFeatureEnrollment getEarlyAccessFeatures getActiveMatchingSurveys getSurveys onSessionId".split(" "),n=0;n<o.length;n++)g(u,o[n]);e._i.push([i,s,a])},e.__SV=1)}(document,window.posthog||[]);
    posthog.init('phc_JWxHyM9Pjm7j73pz9N5JQ7KW6WA0AoC2hbwbDmk1AgT', {api_host: "https://us.i.posthog.com"})
</script>

Both above shared code are not working.

(disclosure I'm an engineer at PostHog helping Vikash here https://posthog.com/questions/recording-iframe-within-an-iframe-within-an-iframe - including as an answer since this is aa bit involved for a comment)
That first code won't work... it checks for posthog's existence but you want to install posthog. If you're not installing posthog then the existence check will never work
the second example you've provided looks correct. you need to include the posthog js snippet - i don't know superset but so long as that script tag is included unchanged by superset then it will run
but you need to configure this to support cross origin recording
so in the snippet the line
   posthog.init('phc_JWxHyM9Pjm7j73pz9N5JQ7KW6WA0AoC2hbwbDmk1AgT', {api_host: "https://us.i.posthog.com"})
needs to be edited
I'll assume the token is the same as the page embedding
and I'll assume the superset page is being embedded as an iframe in the parent
the docs are here https://posthog.com/docs/session-replay/iframes#recording-cross-origin-iframes
so you need to edit it to
posthog.init('phc_JWxHyM9Pjm7j73pz9N5JQ7KW6WA0AoC2hbwbDmk1AgT', {api_host: "https://us.i.posthog.com",
session_recording: {
        // WARNING: Only enable this if you understand the security implications
        recordCrossOriginIframes: true,
    }})

and the parent page needs the same config
that config tells the embedded page to send messages up to the parent
and tells the parent page to listen to messages from children

you can also add config
loaded: function (posthog) {
console.log('posthog has loaded', {config: posthog.config})
    },

to see if posthog loadsa on each page

as per your suggestion I have included the same code in superset's tail_js_custom_extra.html and it was already available in my website.

But it didn't work, I'm sharing the code and steps I followed
  enable_recording_console_log: true, 
  session_recording: {
      // WARNING: Only enable this if you understand the security implications
      recordCrossOriginIframes: true,
  }})
    },``` 

The steps I followed are
npm-install

npm run build

docker-down and up

Paul - I'm also not sure if it's not getting installed because of some superset config mismatch.

If you add a script tag that just tries to console log does that work to test if the script tag is evaluated?

Paul - I checked with simply <script>   console.log('tail_js_custom_extra.html is included'); </script>
But log value is also not visible seems like it's an issues with Superset, waiting for the response from them for further process.

cool, thanks for letting me know... hope you solve it!

No Paul, didn't get a solution for this, I have also posted the same issue on their Github but didn't work the solution they provided waiting for a further response.
Sharing link for your reference as well - https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/29097
